# Where is the of "middle upper arm"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am confused about the meaning of "**middle upper arm**". Is it:

- the "middle part of the upper arm", or
- the "upper part of the middle arm"?

Comment: I would interpret it as 'middle part of the upper arm'.

Answer (score 3):

The former. Firstly, because that's the usual way adjectives of the same class (in this case, locational adjectives) combine in English, with the first modifying the second, and secondly because the "upper arm" is a well-understood phrase, whereas the "middle arm" isn't one of the stock phrases for parts of the body. To what would it refer? The elbow?

Comment: I'd agree. The **middle upper arm** is the _middle_ part of the _upper arm_, while the **upper middle arm** would be the upper part of the elbow. :-)